How to make a SR latch that reacts to edges on its inputs?
I was wondering if there is a circuit that can do the function shown in the picture I have attached?
I want the output signal to be triggered high when signal A goes high. Then I want the output signal to be brought low when signal B goes low. If it helps, in my case signal B cannot be switched on before signal A, or off after signal A. I'm preferably not looking to use something I have to program and is fairly cheap.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So you want something that triggers on the positive edge of one signals and the negative edge of another signal. Now tell us what should happen in every other case (like signal B going low without Signal A going high first and so on).

Signal B is run off of signal A so cannot go high without signal A first.

@SmallFreeRange Would this get the job done? That will work if and only if B always pulses within every A.

Is the requirement a single device that does everything without external components (resistors, capacitors, etc.), or is a small circuit an acceptable answer?  This forum does not like part requests, but loves circuit design.

peri - a possible problem with a simple toggle circuit is synchronization.

Let's assume that you need close to zero delay from the A-rising and B-falling edge to the output. You'd want to forward those edges directly to the output. Thus, the solution generally is to use a passive multiplexer with a control circuit, that switches the output to B when A*B=1, and switches it back to A when A+B=0:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For lowest delay, the mux should be passive: a logic-controlled "analog" switch like 4053 or 4056, etc.
We can simplify this circuit to use only two chips, with one gate left over. Don't forget to tie the unused CMOS gate inputs to a fixed voltage!

simulate this circuit
We can also use CD4066 as the mux - it's still just two chips:

simulate this circuit
The mux can be an active selector if minimal practicable delay is not a concern:

simulate this circuit
The OR1 and AND2 gates contribute to the edge delay from input to output.
Alternatively, if the delay is not so much a concern, we can use a #S/#R latch made from two NAND gates, and edge detectors. This uses just two quad-NAND chips, say 2xCD4011, or 2x74HC00, etc.

simulate this circuit

Thank you very much! I'll go and try the CD4053 and CD4001 solution and let you know how it goes.

What you're asking for can be done with a JK Flipflop..
Since the JK needs a clock I'm creating a clock pulse from the changes in the input signals...


Where does the clock go to though? Depending on logic family, you can't have floating inputs.

Won't this cause Q (the Output signal) to toggle on and off when only signal A is high?

True... let me correct that...

Potentially you want the j-k flipflops async cousin, the s-r latch? It depends on if your signals should be level signaled on a clock, or edge triggers.

@user1937198 it's a question if it's easier to handle the not allowed state of the RS or generate a clock for JK... My first thought was RS too but than decided for JK because it has defined behaviour in every situation.

Rather than 2, 3, or 4 chips, this is a first pass at a single-chip solution.  Besides the lower body count, this circuit presents a buffered, low impedance signal to the downstream circuit(s).  A complimentary output (C-) falls out of the design.
R1-C1 differentiates the leading edge of A (inverted by U1A), and R2-C2 differentiates the trailing edge of B.  These Set and Reset a standard NAND gate flipflop.
The question has zero information about speed, propagation delay, timing, etc, so the gate technology and differentiator component values are SWAGs.

UPDATE:
Early CMOS logic parts (CD4xxx, 4xxxA, 4xxxU) were susceptible to incorrect operation or damage if an input voltage exceeded Vdd.  A common form of this is called "latch-up", where the part behaves as an SCR, pulling excessive current from Vdd.  They also were very susceptible to ESD damage.  B-series CD4000 CMOS and just about everything newer have clamping diodes at the inputs to alleviate both conditions.
A differentiator circuit can act as a charge pump, creating an output voltage that exceeds Vdd.  The gate input's suppression diodes clamp this excess voltage shunting a current spike to the Vdd pin.  However, if the capacitor size is large enough, the current spike through the diode can be large enough to stress it over time.  For added protection, add 1N914 diodes across R1 and R2.  Also, the energy stored in the capacitor can be reduced by increasing the differentiator network impedance, such as increasing the resistance 10x (to 100K) and reducing the capacitance by 10x (to 0.01 uF).

I'm confused as when signal B is switched in this circuit both C and C- will be high and signal B is switched off again signal C will still be high or have I missed something?
As for timing, I would need to measure the propogation delay but they are slow switching human inputs controlling a GPIO pin so slow switching speed or frequency should not be an issue.

This implementation risks the inputs of the later NANDs being pushed to 2*VDD due to capacitive coupling. This may or may not lead to latchup and component destruction - depending on logic family and VDD...

I left that out to see what would happen.  See UPDATE.

I think a Schottky diode would be a safer bet than a 1N914. :)
